# What are the security issues if the local.xml in Magento is publicly accessible?

Tags: security, magento

I know very little about Magento and did not build the site in question myself, but I discovered a client's website's local.xml file was publicly accessible- http://domain.com/app/etc/local.xml which contained the username and password.
I assume that this file shouldn't be publicly accessible, but doesn't Magento automatically block access (by sending a 403 header)?
What are the security implications for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The world would have your DB connection information, also the crypt key is right there so they can break all your customer's secure information.

Magento blocks access to etc from app via .htaccess in that directory.

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Comment: Thanks. Apparently the database doesn't allow external connections, is this still a security concern? Could you give a bit more information on how the crypt key could pose a security threat. What could a hacker do with the crypt key? Are you saying that Magento blocks the /app/ directory out of the box? Just wondering why this file could have been publicly viewable in the first place.

Comment: if it doesn't, that's great and all but it is still info that I wouldn't want anyone having, but remember that in security, there is always someone better, whether they be whitehat or blackhat.  The crypt key is used encrypt CC information, so if they have that they can decrypt the CC info, and have complete access to consumers CC, and no one likes being like Sony or LinkedIn.  It isn't viewable in the first place.  Magento includes that .htaccess as part of its initial install, it had to have been removed by someone.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I believe the site is on an IIS server so I don't know whether that makes a difference.

Comment: _Why could this file be publicly viewable in the first place?_ It's a php web application. A good proportion of php web applications are created to be installed on hosting accounts where the only access is via FTP possibly only to the server doc root and to the database. Everything installs in publicly accessible server space and is protected by .htaccess files. The security implications are if you muck with the Magento installed .htaccess files, you will be creating hazards that will allow your website to be compromised.

Comment: It does make a difference, .htaccess are part of Apache and IIS doesn't read those files.  You would need to block that file from being read by the IIS user or the IIS anonymous user, but PHP would still need to be able to access the directories, you would need to translate the .htaccess data into the web.config in IIS.  http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/557/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig/

Comment: .htaccess is for Apache and Apache type web servers. IIS probably ignores it. Magento is a native LAMP stack web application and needs the protections LAMP stacks provide. You'll also want to check if your var/backup folder is world accessible for download. The local.xml plus your database backup = everyone knows what's in your database. Not a good thing&trade;

Comment: We are always happy to be of assistance, please be sure to accept the answers and up vote comments that have been useful.

Comment: @FiascoLabs where does the var/backup folder hang out? Are there any folders or files that shouldn't be accessible that I should check?

Comment: Look in your document root for the var directory. Backup is under it. Ideally, the media folder and skins folder contents must be visible to the web user. The rest of the content is application and the web user only sees the application output, a combination of database content filtered into Magento's templates.

Comment: I would recommend just downloading the zip from Magento and look at them side by side, to see where they have them by default.  The back folder is in var in the web_root, but only exists if a back up is done.

Comment: The problem is I don't have full ftp access or access to all the settings through the admin panel. The web dev company manages all this.

Comment: Ah.  I would just inform the client the best you can and then if they want to take it to the web dev company for a solution then they can.  I would like to note that Magento only support Apache in the CE editions, below 1.7 and nginx and Apache from 1.7+.  http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements

Comment: It is using Magento v.1.5.0.1, I am not sure, but I am assuming it is the CE edition. Does this mean that my client's website won't be able to upgrade to the latest version due to the fact that it's on IIS?

Comment: It can be upgraded, but the same issues would occur (.htaccess, etc), as with all upgrades, they should be carried out with extreme care, be sure to back up all files and back up the database, I usually recommend performing the upgrade on a dev/staging area first.  You should look at having them migrate to an approved platform so they can get upgrade, and fix whatever they might need to, and get the security fixes.

Comment: Not sure why they're on IIS and not Apache, but I think the migration process might be too painful! I'll see what the web devs say.

Comment: You see this fairly often with developers who do their primary development on WAMP stacks. It's a good indicator that they possibly don't understand the security aspect Magento was created under. If it was being run live on WAMP/XAMPP on Windows Server with proper attention to file permissions, etc. it could be fairly secure. IIS/WAMP/XAMPP require attention to detail to make them websafe with Magento.

Answer (score 2):

[How to move your local.xml to be outside your web root directory structure.](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_move_local.xml_outside_the_doc_root)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to database and encryption key information it can contain info about cache servers.

Answer (score 0):

In a standard Magento installation, that is correctly configured having local.xml file publicly accessible is not a security threat.

That said, if there would occur any deviation from the standard server configuration, and in one way or another it would become possible to read the file all other security measures you might have in place would become absolute.

As such, its highly recommended to have this file not publicly accessible, as a failsafe, if not anything else.